# Can't connect to internet in Ubuntu using bridge adapter

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox, bridge

My host OS is windows XP(SP3), guest OS is Ubuntu 14.04, and virtualBox is 4.3.

I want `XP` and `Ubuntu` to talk to each other, so I choose to use `bridge adapter` network.

`XP`:

```
Windows IP Configuration

    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : cheguangai
    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 54-04-A6-9A-E0-25
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.92
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.1
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.1
```

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-8C-9E
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration IP Address. . . : 169.254.211.66
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

So I add these following lines into `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.8.98 # Arbitrary free static IP
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.8.1
```

After network restart: `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, I still can't access a website in Ubuntu.

In Ubuntu, `ifconfig eth0` prints these:

```
    cheguangai@cheguangai-VB:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:24:27:ed  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe24:27ed/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25891 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2597 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1993335 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:532773 (532.7 KB)
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

after changing your `/etc/network/interfaces` file like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.8.98 # Arbitrary free static IP
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.8.1
```

you need manually to enable the interface through the `ifup` command. :

```
# sudo ifup eth0
```

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

I sovled it.

Edit network configuration in graphic dialog, in `Ipv4` Tab, MUST check `require Ipv4 addressing to complete this connection`, then there will be `Ipv4` info in `ifconfig eth0` outputs.